# How to clear error 1004 on vba on a 16000 lines file?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm currently working on a 16 000 rows excel file

- Column B is the date I want to update
- Column H is the starting date
- Column I is the ending date
- Column K is the number of times date need to be updated (updated on n rows)

The idea is to display all dates from starting date to ending date in column B (one date per column).

You'll find below my current codes. I'm a beginner, it probably includes a lot of mistakes.

```
Sub Dates()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim MyDate As Long
    Dim EndDate As Long
    Dim EndRowA As Long
    Dim EndRowB As Long
    Dim EndRowH As Long
    Dim StartDate As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    StartDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").Value
    MyDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").Value
    EndDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").Value
    EndRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRowH = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    Do While (i <= EndRowH And i <= EndRowA And i <= EndRowB)
        If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            GoTo Continue
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            For k = 1 To ws.Cells(i, k).Value
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Select
                ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "H").Value + 1
                Exit For
Continue:
            Next k
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Can you please provide me with some help, I keep getting error 1004 on line :

```
If ws.Cells(i,"H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
```

Main columns in the spreadsheet should look as follows:

```
Type    Date     Start date   End Date   #

A   01/01/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/02/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/03/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/04/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/05/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/06/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/07/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/08/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/09/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10  
A   01/10/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
B   02/06/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/07/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/08/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/09/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/10/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
```

[image: Table]

I thank you in advance

Comment: Refreshing to see you've qualified your `Cells` and `Rows` references. Also great to see the explicit `.Value`!

Comment: Well `i` is `0` all the time. You don't set a start value for `i` and you don't increment `i` so it stays `0` all day long. And row counting starts with `1` there is no row `0`. That's why you get an error.  So set a valid start row for `i` and do `i = i + 1` in your loop to increment it otherwise you have an endless loop.

Comment: I can see 2 problems: First.. `i` doesn't have a value. Second.. You are not incrementing `i` so your loop will never end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you need to initialize `i` to a numeric value, otherwise row `0` will result with an error.

**Second**, your loop can be improved:

```
Do While (i <= EndRowH And i <= EndRowA And i <= EndRowB)
```

You can look for the `Min` value of these 3 `EndRow`s, like in the section below, and then switch to `For` loop:

```
EndRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(EndRowA, EndRowB, EndRowH)       
For i = 1 To EndRow ' <-- starting loop from the 1st row
```

**Third**: you have `If .Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value Then` and in your `ElseIf` you have `ElseIf .Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value Then`, which is the exact same criteria >> most likely yuo meant to use something else.

**Fourth**: I think you misplaced the location of your `Continue:` label.

See code below for more explanations about your code errors.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dates()

Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim MyDate As Long
Dim EndDate As Long
Dim EndRowA As Long
Dim EndRowB As Long
Dim EndRowH As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim StartDate As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    StartDate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").Value
    MyDate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").Value
    EndDate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").Value
    EndRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRowH = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    ' get the minimumm last row from: EndRowA, EndRowB, EndRowH
    EndRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(EndRowA, EndRowB, EndRowH)

    For i = 1 To EndRow ' <-- starting loop from the 1st row
        If .Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            GoTo Continue
        ElseIf .Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value Then ' <-- same exact criteria as in your If
            For k = 1 To ws.Cells(i, k).Value
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Select ' <-- not sure what do you need this line ???
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "H").Value + 1
                Exit For
Continue: '<-- not sure if this is placed correctly ??
            Next k
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok ok, Thanks a lot, I didn't see all this, I updated all you told me
  For i = 1 To EndRow
        If .Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            GoTo Continue
        ElseIf .Cells(i, "H").Value < .Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            For k = 1 To .Cells(i, "K").Value
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "H").Value + 1
                Exit For
                k = k + 1
            Next k
        End If
But then line before EXIT FOR generates an error 13. I thought it was linked to the "i - 1", but it didn't clear the error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @ClémentHurel Note: you don't need a `k = k + 1`  because `Next k` does that already automatically. And for `i = 1` the row in `.Cells(i - 1, "H").Value + 1` is `0` and therefore doesn't exist.

Comment: I see, so i -1 = 0 on the first loop as i = 1. But do you see a way to get value of the cell in column H and row above, in cell (i,B) . And with your opinion, the code should work as it is written right now? Because when I check online, the code seems to be ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935693/how-do-i-increase-cell-value-in-excel-using-vba-error-type-mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        .Formula = "=IF(H" & .Row - 1 & "<>H" & .Row & ",H" & .Row & ",B" & .Row - 1 & "+1)"
        .Value = .Value
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Kinds of changes everything but way cleaner, unfortunately I don't get a part of the code. Especially about ReDim, it generates error 9 (index is not within selection), do you have any idea?

Comment: @ClémentHurel I tested the code on a test Excel file with over 20,000 rows.  If you're getting an error, then your setup does not match your description.  Please edit your original question to include what your starting data looks like, and what the expected results should be.

Comment: I incuded a screenshot of my table, let me know if you need more information. FYI Date format is in European Format

Comment: @ClémentHurel I changed the cell formatting to be `dd/mm/yyyy`, and I think I see the issue now, you already have all of the necessary rows, you just need the date incremented.  Will update the answer shortly.

Comment: @ClémentHurel Because you already have all of the rows you need, the update is actually very simple.  See updated answer.

Comment: @ClémentHurel Answer has been edited significantly and is much shorter and simpler now.  Refresh your page if you don't see the new code.

Comment: @tigervatar You champion! Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @ClémentHurel You're very welcome. If that works for you, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your loop:

1. `i` is `0` all the time. You don't set a start value for `i` and you don't increment `i` so it stays `0` all day long. And row counting starts with `1` there is no row `0`. That's why you get an error. So set a valid start row for `i` and do `i = i + 1` in your loop to increment it otherwise you have an endless loop.
2. Your `GoTo Continue` jumps right into the `For k` loop. That won't work. Probably you meant the destination `Continue:` to be after the `Next k`
3. `ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Select` is useless. Avoid using select at all.

---

```
Do While (i <= EndRowH And i <= EndRowA And i <= EndRowB)
    If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
        GoTo Continue
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
        For k = 1 To ws.Cells(i, "K").Value
            'ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Select 'does nothing useful here
            ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "H").Value + 1
            Exit For
        Next k
    End If
Continue: 'moved 
    i = i + 1 'increment i
Loop
```

Comment: Ok ok, I changed it to "K" as it is the column I want to check every time:

Comment: @ClémentHurel Well, so is this a question now?